# How to convert camera coordinates to latitudes and longitudes in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I have requirement where i have to convert camera coordinates to latitudes and longitudes in iOS for Augmented Reality. Can we use ARToolkit or any other library for the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "camera coordinates"? Camera doesn't have any relation to coordinates. To get location on ios device you should use CoreLocation framework. Ask for user permission, subscribe to location updates and get coordinates in delegate method.

Comment: I mean based on camera zoom level, places should be shown. If this to be achieved we have to know the boundary within which markers should be shown, boundary can be calculated by using camera zoom level.

Comment: @kanna, I think, what you need - is CoreMotion. Using magnetometer data you can calculate the direction of view. The camera angle of view (without zoom) - is slightly different for every device, although I used the value of 0.94 radians. If you are planning to use zoom, you should know relationship between zoom level and angle of view.

Comment: Thus, having coordinates of your points in polar coordinate system (with pole at user location), direction of view and angle of view in the same coordinate system, you can determine which point is visible at the moment - and render it accordingly on screen. Optionally you may want to consider inclination of device to make your AR more realistic.